# Azimuth, spatialisation, psychoacoustics and whatnots?

Tags: psychoacoustics

Does anybody have some resources regarding psychoacoustics and things such as spatialisation, preferably height (above, below) and how frequencies act when they are coming behind you. I know that there are surround-systems, I know that there are HTRF binaural things as well, but some more details regarding how the frequencies behaves in these types of situations and things such as early reflections and similar. Mainly for personal reasons, but for educational reasons as well. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Since reflections from the pinnae (the things on the sides of our heads most people call "ears") are what creates a lot of the azimuth and spatialization information, the only methods I've seen for capturing this is binaural recording and then playback on headphones. Early reflections are more used by our brains to detect reflectors (walls, trees, rocks etc.) that are close to the sound source(s).

Comment: So what about filtering? I understand that the best approach would be HTRF binaurals, But what exactly happens to sound when it is elevated, and does the thing that happens change past a certain point of elevation?

What exactly happens to sound(waves) when it is located below you or behind you?